# Reflexion on language to develop cross mobile app (android, iphone, wp7, other)

Tags: c#, java, iphone, android, windows-phone-7

I'am a c# developper and I seek the best language to choose to be able to reuse some code in a perspective of port some future apps into mobile devices for free (open source perspective).
Should I use Java (and so learn it), or can uses C#.

Monodroid and monotouch are not free and monotouch requires a mac hardware (I only have norml pc with Linux and Windows and may run mono on both)!

So it will be difficult to use c# for android or iPhone, am i wrong ?

Comment: Android -> Java,
iPhone -> Objective-C,
WP7 -> Silverlight or XNA. As far as I know.

Comment: I am pretty sure some home made cross dev solutions exists already. Look at Angry Birds which looks identical on Android, iPhone, soon on WM7 and blackberry, now in (strongly ofbfuscated) javascript. What is the miracle it is identical ? I dont know which language has to be studied the best to do cross dev, but I am sure some common frameworks and code generators solutions exists already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we (Resco) bet on C# and .Net/Mono. This covers nearly all platforms. (We currently have products on WP7/Android/iOS/WM.)

But taking into account recent developments Mono seems to have very uncertain future. Nobody will tell you right now what's going to happen.